# Eloquent Javascript: Higher Order Functions

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm going through Eloquent Javascript: Higher Order Functions example below and already read questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535316/higher-order-functions-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860664/why-does-this-function-have-a-second-parameter-in-separate-brackets/). But I'm still very confused.

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
noisy(Boolean)(0);
// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

1. How can (0) be passed into noisy(f) since noisy() only takes one parameter and that is (Boolean)? I can see the inner function f(arg) is basically Boolean(0), but I don't understand how two parameters can get passed into a function that only allow one parameter. Would "noisy(Boolean)(0)(1)(2)(3);" be a valid function call? If so, how would you differentiate each value after Boolean within the noisy    function? Which value will be referenced by "arg"?
2. The book noted the example function is modifying another function. Which function is being modified? I'm not understanding what the author meant by "modified".

Comment: noisy(f) returns a function that takes one argument, arg. Calling this function with the sole argument is perfectly valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Higher-order functions in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535316/higher-order-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe `var ModifiedBoolean = noisy(Boolean); console.log(ModifiedBoolean(0))` is easier to understand. Though instead of "modified" the term "wrapped" might be better.

Comment: Depending on what function you pass to `noisy` the behavior of the returned function `function(arg)` is **modified**. Pass an `inc` function for instance and you get a completely different behavior: `noisy(inc)(0)` yields 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the concept of `currying` in JavaScript where you can curry functions to return partially applied functions or pass in other functions

> How can (0) be passed into noisy(f) since noisy() only takes one parameter and that is (Boolean)?

The answer to this is the curried function `noisy()` which expects a function `f` as parameter and returns another function. The returned function has a **closure** over `noisy` and as a result it can identify that `Boolean` was passed as parameter to `noisy` even after it was returned. That's why calling `noisy(Boolean)(0)` basically substitutes `f=Boolean, arg=0`

Refer this for more on **currying**: http://javascript.crockford.com/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/ and **closures**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Thanks for mentioning currying. Another explanation is here: https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't understand how two parameters can get passed into a
> function that only allow one parameter

`noisy` returns a function, `Boolean` is passed to `noisy`, `0` is passed to anonymous function returned from `noisy`, where `f` is `Boolean`, `val` becomes `Boolean(0)`.

For example

```
function fn1(arg1) {
  return function fn2(arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2)
  }
}

// Call fn1, inside fn1 fn2 is called with `"b"` as parameter.
fn1("a")("b") // `a b`, `fn2`
```